# How to make email address variable in Android Studio

Tags: android, email

I'm sending an email in background with a fixed gmail email address (public static final String EMAIL = "abc@gmail.com" and a fixed password (public static final String PASSWORD = "abcd". Now I want to change that. The user should be able to change the email address and send the email with his personal one.

Unfortunately I wasn't that successful in reseach.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We cannot change the value of a final variable once it is initialized.

Comment: Are you sending email by using web service or from android email framework ?

Comment: I'm using web service from gmail. SMTP etc.. is specified to GMAIL. 

@Vickyexpert

Comment: If you are using web service then you just need to prompt user for valid gmail account and password on calling this event, means when user click on send mail you just have to show one dialog box with user name and password so user can enter and send. But main thing is Does user will enter email and password in your app, because this is the question of privacy .

Comment: Ok I got this part but could you explain how to program a Dialog box with an EditText so user can type in username and password?
Never did that before!..
User does not have to enter email and password in my app it's just a thing to try but you're right it's a question of privacy!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you mean by Email eligible.

If you mean eligible(valid) Email address then use this method

```
private boolean isValidEmaillId(String email){

    return Pattern.compile("^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
            + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
            + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
            + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$").matcher(email).matches();
}
```

Comment: With Email eligible I meant that the user of the app can choose the email of sender by himself. Right now the email of sender is fixed / continual and the app always sends email from this address but I want to be able to send email with other address such as yahoo, Hotmail etc.

Comment: you mean you have drop down menu which you have list of addresses(like abc@gmail, abc@yahoo.com)select Email address to send Email. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get your question. maybe this will help.

In Android, non-static final variables can be assigned a value either in constructor or with the declaration. But, static final variables cannot be assigned value in constructor; they must be assigned a value with their declaration.

**For Checking Email Address pattern**

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence myEmail) {
  return !TextUtils.isEmpty(myEmail) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(myEmail).matches();
}
```

Comment: I tried to rewrite my question. Maybe it's easier to understand.